# One of the sections is randomly crashing on the page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a one page site with few sections.. Bootstrap template. One of the sections cause a bug after few refreshes of the site. There are no errors in the console.. nothing and I just don't know how to trace and find the problem.

This is the html part of this section

```
<section id="portfolio" class="section portfolio padding-large text-center" data-section-name="portfolio">
    <div class="container margin-bottom-medium">
        <div class="row margin-bottom-medium wow fadeInUp">
            <h2> Portfolio </h2>
            <div class="line main-bg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper margin-bottom-medium">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <div class="portfolio" style="margin-left:5px;"><a href="#" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio"><img src="img/portfolio/release02-360x360.jpg" alt="">
             <div class="portfolio-overlay hvr-rectangle-out">
                  <h2 class="margin-bottom-small">
                      <strong class="white-color bold-text" style="font-size: 20px;">Portfolio</strong>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="button">Check item</div>
             </div>
           </a>
         </div>
     </div>

    </div> 
    <div class="button light margin-top-medium margin-bottom-medium hvr-grow"><i class="icon-reload"></i><a href="portfolio.php"> Check All</a></div>
</section>
```

This is what I have in main.js from the portfolio section

```
  var container = $('.portfolio-wrapper'); // portfoolio container

container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
  animationEngine: 'best-available',
  animationOptions: {
      duration: 200,
      queue: false
  },
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});

// Split columns for different size layout
function splitColumns() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
  columnNumber = 1; //  default column number
  if (windowWidth > 1200) {
      columnNumber = 4;
  } else if (windowWidth > 767) {
      columnNumber = 3;
  } else if (windowWidth > 600) {
      columnNumber = 2;
  }
  return columnNumber;
}
// Set width for portfolio item
function setColumns() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    columnNumber = splitColumns(),
    postWidth = Math.floor(windowWidth / columnNumber);

container.find('.portfolio-item').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        width: postWidth + 'px'
    });
  });
}
// initialize isotope
function initIsotope() {
  setColumns();
  container.isotope('layout');
}
container.imagesLoaded(function() {
  setColumns();
});
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
   initIsotope();
});
initIsotope();
```

Here are two images in normal state and when it's crashed. Normal behavior
[image: Normal]

Here is when it crashed
[image]

I really don't have an idea of what can be the issue since there are no errors at all. I think that may be a js problem but again I'm not sure.

Edit: Here are the JS which are included in footer in this order:

```
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/twitterFetcher_min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/appear.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrollify.js"></script>
```

Edit2: Wrapping like this?

```
  // initialize isotope
function initIsotope() {
  setColumns();
  container.isotope('layout');
}
container.imagesLoaded(function() {
  setColumns();
});
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
  initIsotope();
});
//initIsotope();
setTimeout(function(){ initIsotope(); }, 0);
```

Comment: Are you loading a third party JS/CSS file?

Comment: Yes, I'm loading few. Will update question with JS

Comment: Question is updated

Comment: I would be interested to know if wrapping your initIsotope() in a setTimeout 'solved' the problem. Also when it loads wrong, does resizing the screen fix  it?

Comment: "Also when it loads wrong, does resizing the screen fix it?" - Yes, when i rezise window it's fixed

Comment: How to wrap initIsotope() in setTimeout

Comment: I would say isotope is being called too early for it to correct place the items. Wrapping the initIsotope in a setTimeout, 0 would likely solved your problem. setTimeout(function(){ initIsotope(); }, 0); Its not entirely ideal though.

Comment: I have updated my question. You mean like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From having a look at similar masonry issues. I would suspect one of these two would solve your issue -

```
$(window).load(function(){
  initIsotope()
});

// or

setTimeout(function(){ initIsotope(); }, 0);
```

Both these are masking the core issue - you should really be reading the section around unloaded media here - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/help.html

I would suggest your content is not fully loaded sometimes and isotope gets confused. Specifying the dimensions lets isotope render correctly despite the images not loading quickly enough. You need to follow this pattern so that slow connections work. Setting timeouts has its uses, but you should fix the underlying issue.

Comment: I have tried `setTimeout(function(){ initIsotope(); }, 0);` and after few refresh's crash again. Will try `$(window).load(function(){ ... });`

Comment: How are you getting these images? Are they inline on the page or are you fetching them via ajax? If via ajax, you would have to wait for them to finish loading

Comment: At last resort, you could try setTimeout(function(){ initIsotope(); }, 1000);

Comment: I get them via database..Not ajax.. query to database is directly there on the file

Comment: With `$(window).load(function(){ ... });` problem is still there

Comment: Well with this `setTimeout(function(){ initIsotope(); }, 1000);` I see how it's crash but them its fixing itself

Comment: Ok, thank's. For now is okay and working. Will try to fix it.